# Audio level in video different between Mac players and other players

Tags: audio, video, encoding

I ripped a dvd of a family event using HandBrake, and increased the gain setting to maximum since the audio on the dvd was extremely quiet. Now when I play the resulting m4v on iTunes, Quicktime, or Mac's spacebar preview, the audio is fine, maybe a little on the quiet side. However, when I play it with VLC or import it into Audacity, Blender, or even iMovie for editing, it's far too loud, and much of it is clipped. Any ideas as to why this is?

Maybe this would be better in an a/v forum, but since the problem seems related to mac players, I thought I'd give it a try here.

Comment: idk for sure, but you've probably added a [DialNorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialnorm) or [ReplayGain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain) type parameter that some software recognises - the really loud ones - & some that don't... the quieter ones.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I'll try posting on StackOverflow; if the answer is this technical that'll be a better bet.